# Definition of the nth derivative? [First post]

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition

If the definition of the derivative is 
$$
f^\prime(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$
Would it make sense that the nth derivative would be (I know that the 'n' in delta x to the nth power is useless) 
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n \choose k}\dfrac{f(x+\Delta x(n-k))}{\Delta x^n}
$$
I came to this conclusion using this method
$$
f^\prime(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$
(this is correct right?)
$$
f^{\prime\prime}(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f^\prime(x+\Delta x) - f^\prime(x)}{\Delta x}=$$
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{f((x+\Delta x)+\Delta x)-f(x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x}-\dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}}{\Delta x}=$$
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)}{\Delta x^2}
$$
After following this method a couple of times(I think I used it to the 5th derivative) I
noticed the pattern of
$$(a-b)^n$$
And that is how i arrived at 
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n \choose k}\dfrac{f(x+\Delta x(n-k))}{\Delta x^n}
$$
Have I made a fatal error somewhere or does this definition actually follow through?

Thanks for your time I really appreciate it.

P.S. Any input on using tags will be appreciated.

Comment: looks good to me. Sometime folks prefer  centered formulas. That is to make $x$ to be center of all points considered as opposed to having all other points after or before $x$. That gives better agreement in numerical work.

Comment: I'd be concerned that the $\Delta x$ from say the second derivative is a different object than the $\Delta x$ from the first derivative. You have a limit involving $\Delta x^n$ as $\Delta x\to0$, but the straightforward iterated interpretation would involve a limit $\Delta x_1\Delta x_2\cdots\Delta x_n$ as $\Delta x_n\to0$, $\Delta x_{n-1}\to0$, ..., $\Delta x_1\to0$. And I would guess that there are functions where the iterated (latter) limit is one thing, and the amalgamated limit (the former) is something else.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Sense the end result does not change it was a bit hard to notice. Thanks alex.jordan

Comment: This method was used by Riemann (for 2nd order version only, I think) as a slightly weaker notion than ordinary 2nd order differentiability that he applied in the study of trigonometric series. The first few sentences of J. Marshall Ash's 1970 paper [*A characterization of the Peano derivative*](http://math.depaul.edu/mash/Peano.pdf) may be useful. For more than you'd ever possibly want to know about this topic, see Satya Mukhopadhyay's 2012 book [**Higher Order Derivatives**](http://books.google.com/books?id=caFX9VwE5NgC) (I was able to see, in "preview", the table of contents).

Comment: Thanks Dave L. Renfro. That book looks like it will answer most of my questions regarding this subject.

Comment: @tiendbz I'm still not sure, but I think it might be possible to find a function $f$ where $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\sum\limits_{k=0}^2(-1)^k\binom{2}{k}\frac{x+h(2-k)}{h^2}$ is not equal to $\lim\limits_{h_2\to0}\frac{\lim_{h_1\to0}\frac{f(x+h_2+h_1)-f(x+h_2)}{h_1}-\lim_{h_1\to0}\frac{f(x+h_1)-f(x)}{h_1}}{h_2}$. I could be wrong, and maybe these things are provably equal. But I can't help but feel that there could be a pathological $f$ where these are not equal. In general, the iterated limit as $h_2\to0,h_1\to0$ need not equal a corresponding limit as $h\to0$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta ^{n}f(x)}{\Delta x^{n}} = f^{(n)}(x)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543105/prove-that-lim-delta-x-rightarrow-0-frac-delta-nfx-delta-xn)

Comment: The derivative is inherently dependent on the function in a very direct way. Thus $f'(a)$ depends on values of $f$ near (and on) $a$. And similarly $f''(a)$ depends on values of $f'$ near $a$ (which in turn depend on values of $f$ near $a$). But the dependence of $f''(a)$ on values of $f$ is much more indirect than its dependence on values of $f'$. It is better to defined n-th derivative as "derivative" of "(n - 1)-th derivative" rather than in terms of the original function. The limit formula you have mentioned is correct provided n-th derivative exists and not the other way round.

Comment: It is possible to construct an example of a function where the limit formula gives a value but function is not differentiable n-times according to accepted definition.

Comment: @Paramanand Sigh I see. If this is not the definition of the nth derivative can i still use it or is it flawed in the way that alex.jordan describes it?

Comment: @tiendbz: For most usual well behaved functions (i.e. function whose n-th derivatives exist) this can be used to calculate the n-th derivative directly by a single limit operation. But there can be cases where such a limit exists, but the function itself is not differentiable n times.

Comment: Hi @ParamanandSingh... I write you beceause in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4731325/909869) to a question I did, it is used the same procedure shown in the question above, and since you have made here some observations, I hope you could visit also the mentioned answer in order to check if its OK. Beforehand, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably not a good *definition* of the $n$th derivative.  To see this, consider the case  $n = 2$:
$$
f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x + 2h) - 2f(x + h) + f(x)}{h^2}
$$
Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows.  First, define $f(0) = 0$.
Now define $f$ on the intervals $\left[-1, -\tfrac12\right)$ and $\left(\tfrac12, 1\right]$ to be your favorite unbounded function, for instance $\frac{1}{x^2 - 1/4}$ is a good choice.
Now, for any $x$, let $k$ be the unique integer such that $2^k x$ is contained in one of these intervals, and define $f(x) = 2^{-k} f(2^k x)$.

This construction satisfies $f(2h) = 2f(h)$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$, so the derivative formula above gives
$$
f''(0)
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2h) - 2f(h) + f(0)}{h^2}
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h^2}
= 0
$$
However, $f$ is wildly discontinuous at $0$, and is in fact unbounded in any neighborhood containing $0$.

Comment: Does this come from the fact that he should have used another variable for the second $\Delta x$ so as to not confuse it with the first?

Comment: @DanielV Yes, probably if there were more than one variable it would work as a definition.  See also my question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724339/define-second-derivative-f-without-using-first-derivative-f), which has not yet been answered.

Answer (score -2):

when you did for f''(x) you are taking both limits as a single limit for delta x. what I did is take $h_1$ for first limit and $h_2$ for second limit, so that nth derivative is limit $(h_1, h_2, h_3,.... h_n)$ --> $(0,0,0,....,0)$ and some function.