$\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}(1/f^k(x))^{(n)}f^{1+k}(x) = (f(x))^{(n)}$
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$

Prove that
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}
\binom{n + 1}{k + 1}
\left[\dfrac{1}{\on{f}^{k}\left(x\right)}\right]
^{\left(n\right)}
\on{f}^{1 + k}\left(x\right) = \left[\on{f}\left(x\right)\right]^{\left(n\right)}.
$$
Note that $f^k(x) = (f(x))^k$ and $f^{(n)}(x) = \dfrac d{dx^n}f(x)$.

Since $\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}$ it follows that the sum is $$\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(\dfrac1{f^k(x)}\right)^{(n)}f^{1+k}(x)+\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\left(\dfrac1{f^k(x)}\right)^{(n)}f^{1+k}(x).$$ Is this the same as $(f(x))^{(n)}$?
Note that $\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}(k+n+1)^m = n^m$ and $\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1} = 1$.

Can you clarify your notation of $f^k(x)$ and $f^{(n)}(x)$

Just an idea (I don't know if this would work). Assuming $f$ is smooth it might be helpful to prove the case where it is a polynomial function, then use Weierstrass' approximation theorem for the general case. Not sure since there must be a limit interversion somewhere.

What is the context for this formula ? Did you arrive at it from a similar process as the one described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702185/definition-of-the-nth-derivative-first-post ?

Generic hint: write this down explicitly (no summation) for small cases $n = 0, 1, 2, 3$ and see if you can recognize a pattern. Also, sometimes these kinds of identities are the inverses of identities that are easier to prove, and you can extrapolate the formulas from these small cases.

The context of this question had come when I just input $d/dx^n(1/f(x))$ into Wolfram Alpha and it gave me this. How did Wolfram Alpha get this?

I was going to delete the complex-analysis and complex-integration tags, but upon seeing the answer from user @Marko maybe they are relevant?

Suppose for the moment that $x$ is a complex number. We
will assume $f(x)$ and $1/f(x)$  are analytic at $x$ so
they both  have power  series there with  some non-zero
radius of convergence. Take $\rho\ll$ the lesser of the
two and  take $\rho=1$ if both  converge everywhere. We
then get for the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n+1\choose k+1}
f^{k+1}(x)
\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-x|=\rho}
\frac{1}{(z-x)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{f^k(z)} \; dz.$$
This is
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-x|=\rho} \frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n+1\choose k+1}
f^{k+1}(x) \frac{1}{f^{k+1}(z)}\; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-x|=\rho}
\frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{n+1}} \; dz
\\ + \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-x|=\rho}
\frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{n+1}} \sum_{k=-1}^n (-1)^k {n+1\choose k+1}
f^{k+1}(x) \frac{1}{f^{k+1}(z)}\; dz
\\ = f^{(n)}(x) - \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-x|=\rho}
\frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{n+1}}
\left[1-\frac{f(x)}{f(z)}\right]^{n+1} \; dz
\\ = f^{(n)}(x) - \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-x|=\rho}
\frac{1}{f^n(z)}
\left[\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}\right]^{n+1} \; dz
= f^{(n)}(x).$$
Expanding the bracketed term  into a power series about
$x$ we find
$$g(z) = f'(x)+f''(x)(z-x)/2+f'''(x)(z-x)^2/6+\cdots$$
so it goes  to a constant $f'(x)$ with no  more pole at
$z=x.$  More  importantly  it   is  convergent  in  the
neighborhood  of  $x$  so  it  represents  an  analytic
function there.   Integrating $g^{n+1}(z)/f^n(z)$ which
is the product  of two analytic terms we  obtain a zero
contribution  from  the  integral which  concludes  the
argument.

We show the following formula is valid for $n\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{D_x^n\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{1}{f^{k+1}}D_x^nf^k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Here we have the $n$-th derivative of a composition $g\circ f$ of functions $f$ and $g$ with $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. A formula to calculate the $n$-th derivative of composite functions is stated as Theorem 8.1 in H.W. Gould's Combinatorial Identities called:
Hoppe Form of Generalized Chain Rule.
Let $D_f$ represent differentiation with respect to $f$ and $f=f(x)$. Hence $D^n_x g(f)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$.  The following is valid for $n\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
D_x^n g(f)=\sum_{q=0}^n\left(D_f^qg(f)\right)\frac{(-1)^q}{q!}\sum_{k=0}^q(-1)^k\binom{q}{k}f^{q-k}D_x^nf^k\tag{2}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (2) with $g(f)=1/f$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{D_x^n\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)}
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^n\left(D_f^q\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\right)
\frac{(-1)^q}{q!}\sum_{k=0}^q(-1)^k\binom{q}{k}f^{q-k}D_x^nf^k}\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
We calculate the $q$-th derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ and get
\begin{align*}
D_x^q\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=(-1)^qq!\frac{1}{x^{q+1}}
\end{align*}
Using this identity with $x$ replaced by $f$ we can put it into (3) and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{D_x^n\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)}
&=\sum_{q=0}^n\left((-1)^qq!\frac{1}{f^{q+1}}\right)
\frac{(-1)^q}{q!}\sum_{k=0}^q(-1)^k\binom{q}{k}f^{q-k}D_x^nf^k\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^q(-1)^k\binom{q}{k}\frac{1}{f^{k+1}}D_x^nf^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{1}{f^{k+1}}\left(D_x^nf^k\right)\sum_{q=k}^n\binom{q}{k}\tag{4}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{1}{f^{k+1}}D_x^nf^k}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.
Comment:

In (4) we exchange the order of the sums.

In (5) we apply the Hockey stick identity.


