# Is there an easier way to find the "natural" integration constant?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose we take consequtive derivatives of a function at a point and then interpolate them with Newton series (Newton interpolation formula) so to obtain a smooth curve.

$$f^{(s)}(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {s}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(k)}(x)$$

If the series converges at $s=-1$ we take this value to be the "natural" value of antiderivative of $f$ at the point $x$ (assuming that integral is the -1-th derivative).

For instance, for function $f(x)=a^x$ the expansion converges (if converges, which is not the case for all $a$) to $a^x (\ln a)^s$, or $(\ln a)^s$ at $x=0$. Thus antiderivative of $a^x$ should naturally have value of $\frac{1}{\ln a}$ at $x=0$.

Is there an easier way to obtain this value, and possibly, more universal (working where the series diverges)?

Comment: It seems to me that your series converges at $s=-1$ extremely rarely: it diverges whenever $f$ is a polynomial, for example. Perhaps extrapolation via polynomial interpolation formulas is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Rahul on the other hand, by decomposing the trigonometric functions into exponentials and applying the rule derived above and generalised to all exponential bases, one can see that natural integral of $\cos x$ is $\sin x$ and natural integral of $\sin x$ is $-\cos x$, that is $-1$ in zero. But applying the series directly to sine and cosine would not work, it will diverge. Thus I am seeking a method of finding the same value but which would work for say, sine and cosine directly.

Comment: @Rahul it seems the other method I found, resolves the question of polinomials! Only for $f(x)=const$ the expansion diverges, for $f(x)=x^n$ where n is integer, the expansion always gives $0$.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the inner integral diverge for any polynomial $f$?

Comment: @Rahul it seems it does not. But I have just implemented the formula in Mathematica, and this is just what I obtained, it uses its own tables of Fourier transforms (the FurierTransform function more often converges than just integral, although gives the same result). It extensively uses Dirac Delta function.

Comment: @Rahul also it diverges for odd negative n (which is understandable given that the integrals have a pole in zero) and converges only in generalized sence when n is negetive and even (then the pole in zero has opposite signs). But shifting these functions one still establish the constant, say, in x=1.

Comment: @Rahul and for n=0 the value also can be estimated as zero because $\delta(x)/x$ is an odd function whose integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ should be zero. This coincides with the notion that natural integral of an even function should be always zero in x=0 because it is odd.

Comment: Don't trust everything Mathematica tells you. Take $f(x)=x$, and the inner integral becomes $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} t e^{i\omega t}\,\mathrm dt$ which doesn't converge for any $\omega$.

Comment: @Rahul for what it does not converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using the exponential Fourier transform for non-periodic functions from [this paper](http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_24/24_1_fourier_trnsfm.pdf) one can derive at least one additional method:

$$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i\omega x} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt \, d\omega $$

integrating by $x$ and applying the natural integration of exponent rule we get:

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i\omega x}}{i\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt \, d\omega $$

Now, for $x=0$, we obtain:

$$f^{(-1)}(0)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega $$

Check if I am wrong.

Unfortunately this method converges even more rarely. One function for which it works is $ f(x)=x e^{-x^2}$, in this case $f^{(-1)}(0)=-\frac1{2}$. For $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ the method gives $f^{(-1)}(0)=0$

Using tables for Fourier transform we can also get for $f(x)=\sin x$, $f^{(-1)}(0)=-1$, for $f(x)=\cos x$, $f^{(-1)}(0)=0$, for $f(x)=(\sin x)^3$, $f^{(-1)}(0)=-\frac23$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting way we can go about this. It can be shown that (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543105/prove-that-lim-delta-x-to-0-frac-delta-nfx-delta-xn-fn)), if we replace $f(x)$ with $F$, and then replace $F^n$ with $f(x+nh)$, we have

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{F-1}h\right)^n$$

Notice the neat fact that $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{F-1}{h}=f'(x)$. For example, expanding the above for $n=2$ gives the limit formula

$f''(x)=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{F-1}h\right)^2=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{F^2-F+1}{h^2}\right)=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}\right)$

which is readily verified using L'Hopital. This has the disadvantage of sometimes evaluating derivatives when they don't exist, but will always correctly evaluate the derivative if it exists. If we consider $f^{(-1)}(x)$ to be the integral of $f(x)$, then we have

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{F-1}h\right)^{-1}=-\lim_{h\rightarrow0}h\cdot\left( \frac{1}{1-F}\right)=-\lim_{h\to0}h \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}F^k$$

Since the limit of a series is unique if it exists, then we can define (using formal power series if necessary) the "natural" antiderivative of $f(x)$ as

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=-\lim_{h\to0}h \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(x+hk)$$

Unfortunately, the sum is not always well-defined (i.e. $f(x)=x$ obviously cannot be summed properly), but it does, for example, define $\int \cos(x)=\sin(x)$, or $\int e^x=e^x$.

One advantage of this derivation is that it is easily generalised for any order integral or derivative. Using the fact that $(F-1)^{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty{n\choose k}F^k(-1)^{n-k}$, we have

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{F-1}h\right)^n=\lim _{h\rightarrow0}\left( \frac{(F-1)^{n}}{h^n}\right)=\lim_{h\to0} h^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^\infty{n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k}f(x+hk)$$
is the "natural" differentigral **for any n** where the above is defined (even non-integer $n$).

EDIT:For $e^x$,$-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{x+hk}=-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}he^x \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{hk}=-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{he^x}{1-e^h}=e^x$. Note that the sum is a **formal** power series; the sum above does not actually converge whenever $h>0$, and only sort of represents adding them all together. When $h>0$, it does not converge, but the most logical value would be extending it using it the geometric series formula. When $h<0$, the series converges, and the $h$ cancels the negative.

For $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, their integrals are the imaginary and real parts of $-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{i (x+hk)}$, respectively. This evaluates similarly:

$-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{i (x+hk)}=-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}he^{ix} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty e^{ihk}=-e^{ix}\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{h}{1-e^{ih}}=-ie^{ix}=i (-\cos(x))+\sin(x)$

Comment: Well, the post linked above shows a limit definition of the nth derivative which looks remarkably the binomial expansion of $(F-1)^n$. The result is true, and it matches up really nicely with the substitution I did. As for why this substitution fits so perfectly, I have no idea. I even tried to receive an answer to why here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903481/nth-derivative-of-fx-using-limit-definition. Instead I got the tumbleweed achievement :/ So I can tell you that the substitution is a neat thing that coincides with the limit, but I can't tell you why it coincides.

Comment: Otherwise, this is a really neat way to define the natural derivative or integral of any order, and the nice thing is that it is really easy to derive on the spot if you remember the substitution.

Comment: Err, by the way, your formula looks like the integral sum (definition of definite integral) for $-\int_x^\infty f(t) dt$. This should give 1 in $x=0$ only for $-e^{-x}$ and actually far from "natural integral". Am I missing something?

Comment: How you got the results for sine and exp? Look at the formula at the bottom of the first page here: http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Engineering%20maths%20first%20aid%20kit/latexsource%20and%20diagrams/8_12.pdf or at the formula (1) here: http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap15/15_1.pdf It is Riemann sum (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for $-\int_x^\infty f(t)dt$

Comment: And look also that your definition just does not depend on the value of the function at negative $x$, completely.

Comment: How you got positive value for $e^x$ by summing all-positive terms and taking it with negative sign? For exponent all the terms under sum are positive.

Comment: See edit above for $e^x$, $\sin(x)$, and $\cos(x)$. As for the fact that it equals the integral you mentioned, not quite. If you take the some for positive $h$, $f^{(-1)}(x)=-\int_{x}^\infty f(t) dt$, but for negative $h$, $f^{(-1)}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$. The sum isn't quite the same due to the infinities involved on top of the sum; note that a reimann sum doesn't normally have an infinity on top of the sum. So the sum is not quite equal to the reimann integral, it's its own thing.

Comment: Riemann sum has infinity on top of the sum if the integral has infinity on top of the sum. If $h$ is negative, the integral will be $-\int_{-\infty}^x f(x)$. The limit without sign before $h$ will exist if and only if $-\int_{-\infty}^x f(x)=-\int_{x}^{\infty} f(x)$. This is not the case for any of the functions you mentioned, neither for sin or exponent. And for sin and cos neither of these integrals exists. So this suggestion is total rubbish.

Comment: "When h>0, it does not converge, but the most logical value would be extending it using it the geometric series formula. When h<0, the series converges, and the h cancels the negative." - so, you have just "discovered" that $-\int_{-\infty}^x e^x$ converges, while $-\int_{x}^{\infty} e^x$ does not. Very novel!